# Forcing Parameters on a function without declaring them

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5

I did some research on this and i don't have much hope that this is possible, but maybe there is a JS Wizard amongst you that has an idea on how to solve this.

I have a JS function like this:

```
{
    loadConfiguration: function(){
      theConfig.oneConfigOption = true;
      theConfig.anotherConfigOption = false;
    }
}
```

This is kind of an interface in an old software part. As of now, `theConfig` has always been a  global variable. Since i don't like global variables i want define `theConfig` object from outside the function.

The problem is, that for backwards compatibility reasons, the signature of the function must always stay `function()` and the reference on which the objects needs to be set must always be named `theConfig` so that the above code is still a valid configuration loader. **In fact i can't change anything in the file where this code block lives.**

The only place where i can change is where the function is called (because it is called in another file, which can be updated from one version to another:

```
loadConfiguration();
```

I can do anything here.. wrapper functions, closures or something like that. So my question is, can you think of a way to force the references to `theConfig` of `loadConfiguration` to point to an object i define when calling the function **without** changing its signature?

Comment: any specific reason that you tag ECMA script ?

Comment: eh.. because it IS ECMA script..

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're aiming for, but if you are allowed to get rid of `theConfig` (use a version of it that isn't `window.theConfig`), et cetera, then you can use an IIFE.

```
var funcs = {
    loadConfiguration : (function () {
        var theConfig = {};

        //or, if you prefer...
        theConfig = some.object.somewhere.else.config;
        return function () {
        // this now resolves to the `theConfig` which is in the closure
        // created by the IIFE
            theConfig.one = true;
        };
    }());
};
```

You could even use that IIFE to pass in the location of `theConfig`.  The important thing to note here is that `theConfig` ***MUST EXIST BEFORE THESE IIFE RUN***

```
loadConfiguration : (function (theConfig) {
    return function () { theConfig.x = 3; };
}(newConfigObject))
```

If neither of those are what you're looking for, then be a little more specific about what you'd like to get from it.

### **EDIT**

Based on your update, I have a horrible, awful idea, which theoretically works.
It's ugly, it's ninja-ish, and it's not something that I'd necessarily put in my final product.
That said, it should be pretty predictable, *** AS LONG AS THE FUNCTION YOU'RE REPLACING DOESN'T NEED ACCESS TO CLOSURES*** -- `this` can be hacked around, using call or apply, but if the function is trying to access something else which is a global (or worse, was defined in a closure, though it doesn't look like it), then THOSE will need to be imported, too.

Have a look:
    // the place your "loadConfig" currently lives
    var codeblock = {
        // the function we want to swap the value of
        target_func : function () {
            theVar.prop = 1;
            theVar.attr = 2;
        }
    };
    // the new config object we want to use
    var alternate = {
        config : {}
    };

```
// this whole thing would get injected somewhere into the page
// put it where you're about to fire your stuff
(function () {
    // the name of the variable doesn't actually matter right here
    // but I'm doing it for consistency
    var theVar = alternate.config,
        // grabbing the function as a string
        string = codeblock.target_func.toString(),
        // using regex to remove the `"function anonymous() {" + "}"` wrapper
        bare_func = string.replace(/^function[^{]+{/, "")
                          .replace(/}$/,""),

        // using the new Function constructor to pass in "theVar" (where the name matters)
        // the constructor doesn't accept closures, but any function that is created inside of the constructor does
        // so we return a new function (with the exact contents of the original function
        // but now, `theVar` is a parameter we're passing in 
        new_func = new Function ("theVar", "return function () {" + bare_func + "};"),
        // this is the new function returned from the constructor, and we're passing in "theVar"
        // again, name on the outside doesn't matter -- name in the `new Function` constructor DOES
        enclosed = new_func(theVar);

    // putting the function back where we stole it from
    codeblock.target_func = enclosed;
}());
```

If we ran `codeblock.target_func();` before, it would have set

```
window.theVar.prop = 1;
window.theVar.attr = 2;
```

...but if we call the function now...

```
codeblock.target_func();

alternate.config.prop;  // 1
alternate.config.attr;  // 2
```

Comment: i can't get rid of anything in the first code block. The first code block must stay as it is.

Comment: Right, but my solution isn't getting rid of anything in the code-block. The IIFE which I wrote compiles AS the block is compiling, so by the time you have "created" the block and assigned it to a var, `loadConfiguration === function () { theConfig.oneConfigOption = true; }` Because *during* compile-time, the IIFE runs and finds the new value you set for `theConfig`.  Which means that `theConfig` needs to exist and be set *BEFORE* this whole block of code is assigned to its var. But if it is, then you end up with exactly what you asked for (same footprint, same config name, different object).

Comment: Okay to make things more clear. I can't change anything in the FILE where the first code block is located, because this file exists that way on customer systems and is not meant to be overwritten since it is a configuration file edited by the customer. I'll edit my question...

Comment: @Chris, that certainly makes things more interesting.  Okay, if that's the case then I don't have enough info -- is there anything stopping you from just overwriting the function in the block, when you get to the point where you're ready to call it? ie: load the user's file as-is, and then overwrite the function when the app-files load in? Does the function require access to closures? Does the function call `this`?

Comment: @Chris There's a theoretical solution.  Theoretical because it's dependent upon the rest of your needs.  But basically, saving the string-version of the function, constructing a new function (with the `new Function` constructor), naming the parameters what you're replacing (AND whatever else has to be imported back in), and in that constructor, returning a new copy of the function, then calling the constructor with all of the replacement values/objects, and saving over the old copy of the function. ...all things considered, you might just rewrite the function at this point, but there it is.